# Java ElasticSearch API search multiple possible values

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm searching in multiple fields, and I want to get results if the record matches a specific value (entry.getValue()) or the String "ALL"

Here is my code, but it's not working.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(MY_INDEX);
final BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
searchRequest.source().query(booleanQuery);
final BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery= QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
              booleanQuery.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), "ALL");
        }
```

I'm using JDK 11 and ES 7.1

Comment: Hi Lina, please provide additional information about the version of Elasticsearch and java client you are using and also the structure of your documents that you are trying to find. The additional code around your query and how you are executing the query might also be relevant. Best samy

Comment: Hi @samy, I added some info to my initial post, now I just get an Internal Server error... :(

Comment: Hi Lina, what server error do you get? I recommend that you add as much information to your question as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code written for country index which is searching for data provided in map. Customize it according to your needs.

```
//using map for country
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("country" , "FRANCE");
    map.put("countryCode", "FR");
    //List of should queries this will go in should clause of bool query
    List<Query> shouldQueryList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :map.entrySet()) {
        //list of terms to match i.e value from map and all.
        List<FieldValue> list = Arrays.asList(FieldValue.of(entry.getValue()), FieldValue.of("ALL"));
        //Terms query
        Query query = new Query.Builder().terms(termsQueryBuilder -> termsQueryBuilder
                .field(entry.getKey())
                .terms(termQueryField -> termQueryField
                        .value(list))).build();
        shouldQueryList.add(query);
    }

    try {
        //running search from elastic search java client 7.16.3
        SearchResponse<Country> response = elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest -> searchRequest
                        .query(qBuilder -> qBuilder
                                .bool(boolQueryBuilder -> boolQueryBuilder
                                        //using should query list here
                                        .should(shouldQueryList)))
                , Country.class);
        response.hits().hits().forEach(a -> {
            //Print matching country name in console
            System.out.println(a.source().getCountry());
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Above code will generate query like this :

```
{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"terms":{"country":["FRANCE","ALL"]}},{"terms":{"countryCode":["FR","ALL"]}}]}}}
```